# query to get frequency distribution of times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

here is my data:

```
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| ID | DateTime Entered | DateTime Completed |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 6/17/2011 10:08  | 6/18/2011 14:39    |
|  2 | 5/10/2011 9:29   | 5/15/2011 17:29    |
|  3 | 3/2/2009 9:30    | 3/3/2009 13:40     |
|  4 | 3/3/2009 11:36   | 3/4/2009 16:39     |
|  5 | 3/3/2009 11:37   | 3/4/2009 16:39     |
|  6 | 3/3/2009 11:38   | 3/4/2009 16:39     |
|  7 | 3/3/2009 11:38   | 3/4/2009 16:38     |
|  8 | 3/3/2009 11:38   | 3/5/2009 9:08      |
|  9 | 1/10/2011 9:43   | 1/11/2011 13:13    |
| 10 | 2/11/2011 12:20  | 2/12/2011 15:01    |
| 11 | 8/14/2009 10:20  | 8/17/2009 15:56    |
| 12 | 11/19/2008 9:45  | 11/20/2008 14:56   |
| 13 | 2/10/2011 13:50  | 2/11/2011 19:36    |
| 14 | 8/14/2009 10:23  | 8/17/2009 15:56    |
| 15 | 8/17/2009 9:43   | 8/18/2009 13:56    |
| 16 | 8/17/2009 9:43   | 8/19/2009 6:47     |
| 17 | 8/14/2009 10:28  | 8/17/2009 15:56    |
| 18 | 12/17/2008 10:03 | 12/18/2008 11:07   |
| 19 | 1/13/2009 9:41   | 1/14/2009 18:11    |
| 20 | 1/20/2009 9:18   | 1/21/2009 15:08    |
| 21 | 2/12/2009 10:53  | 2/13/2009 15:21    |
| 22 | 1/20/2009 9:19   | 1/21/2009 15:08    |
| 23 | 1/13/2009 9:50   | 1/15/2009 8:45     |
| 24 | 1/13/2009 9:50   | 1/14/2009 14:40    |
| 25 | 1/13/2009 9:36   | 1/14/2009 18:11    |
| 26 | 12/17/2008 10:06 | 12/18/2008 11:06   |
| 27 | 12/17/2008 10:04 | 12/18/2008 11:06   |
| 28 | 3/30/2010 9:20   | 3/31/2010 13:44    |
| 29 | 1/25/2010 9:33   | 1/26/2010 14:20    |
| 30 | 1/30/2009 11:21  | 2/2/2009 14:44     |
| 31 | 6/17/2010 9:07   | 6/18/2010 14:17    |
| 32 | 6/16/2010 10:24  | 6/17/2010 16:20    |
| 33 | 6/14/2010 9:33   | 6/15/2010 8:52     |
| 34 | 5/27/2010 9:15   | 5/28/2010 14:15    |
| 35 | 5/27/2010 10:16  | 5/28/2010 15:51    |
| 36 | 5/21/2010 9:15   | 5/23/2010 13:05    |
| 37 | 5/19/2010 10:08  | 5/20/2010 13:33    |
| 38 | 6/30/2010 11:41  | 7/1/2010 18:16     |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
```

here is the format i want to put it in. for a specific year, let's call it `2008`:

```
Time Completed  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
12AM    1                                           
1AM                             2               1
2AM     1           1                   1       
3AM                                             3
4AM                 342     1                   
.                                   32          34
.                   42                          
.                                               
NEXT DAY 12AM       2                   1                   
NEXT DAY 1AM                    1                           
.                                               
.
```

............

`DateTime Entered` gives us the starting day and `DateTime Completed` gives us the time when completed.

for example for the first one. it would have a completed time of `14:39` whereas for the second one it would be `5th day 15:29`. the third one would be `2nd day 13:40`

thank you so much for your advice and guidance. i would be most grateful if you could point me into the right direction.

a SQL or SSRS solution would be ideal.

Comment: does the field `...Entered` matter? or is everything based on the field `...Completed`?

Comment: thank you for your question. if completed DAY is the same as entered DAY then we just use ENTERED DATETIME, however if the DAYS are different, then we would do "2nd day 12:49" or "5th day 4:43"

Comment: maybe write a query that extracts the Month and the Hour into seperate fields

Comment: have you started to write a query based on the data ? ... you need to write a query and then feed the results into SSRS. The results of the query will need a field for `Year`, `Month` and this special `Completed` section that you have detailed

Comment: @whytheq no i have not, can you please get me started on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to include sorting:

```
create table tblTest (ID int , Entered datetime, Completed datetime)

set dateformat mdy

insert into tblTest values (1,'6/17/2011 10:08','6/18/2011 14:39')
insert into tblTest values (  2 ,'5/10/2011 9:29','5/15/2011 17:29')
insert into tblTest values (  3 ,'3/2/2009 9:30','3/3/2009 13:40')
insert into tblTest values (  4 ,'3/3/2009 11:36','3/4/2009 16:39')
insert into tblTest values (  5 ,'3/3/2009 11:37','3/4/2009 16:39')
insert into tblTest values (  6 ,'3/3/2009 11:38','3/4/2009 16:39')
insert into tblTest values (  7 ,'3/3/2009 11:38','3/4/2009 16:38')
insert into tblTest values (  8 ,'3/3/2009 11:38','3/5/2009 9:08')
insert into tblTest values (  9 ,'1/10/2011 9:43','1/11/2011 13:13')
insert into tblTest values ( 10 ,'2/11/2011 12:20','2/12/2011 15:01')
insert into tblTest values ( 11 ,'8/14/2009 10:20','8/17/2009 15:56')
insert into tblTest values ( 12 ,'11/19/2008 9:45','11/20/2008 14:56')
insert into tblTest values ( 13 ,'2/10/2011 13:50','2/11/2011 19:36')
insert into tblTest values ( 14 ,'8/14/2009 10:23','8/17/2009 15:56')
insert into tblTest values ( 15 ,'8/17/2009 9:43','8/18/2009 13:56')
insert into tblTest values ( 16 ,'8/17/2009 9:43','8/19/2009 6:47')
insert into tblTest values ( 17 ,'8/14/2009 10:28','8/17/2009 15:56')
insert into tblTest values ( 18 ,'12/17/2008 10:03','12/18/2008 11:07')
insert into tblTest values ( 19 ,'1/13/2009 9:41','1/14/2009 18:11')
insert into tblTest values ( 20 ,'1/20/2009 9:18','1/21/2009 15:08')
insert into tblTest values ( 21 ,'2/12/2009 10:53','2/13/2009 15:21')
insert into tblTest values ( 22 ,'1/20/2009 9:19','1/21/2009 15:08')
insert into tblTest values ( 23 ,'1/13/2009 9:50','1/15/2009 8:45')
insert into tblTest values ( 24 ,'1/13/2009 9:50','1/14/2009 14:40')
insert into tblTest values ( 25 ,'1/13/2009 9:36','1/14/2009 18:11')
insert into tblTest values ( 26 ,'12/17/2008 10:06','12/18/2008 11:06')
insert into tblTest values ( 27 ,'12/17/2008 10:04','12/18/2008 11:06')
insert into tblTest values ( 28 ,'3/30/2010 9:20','3/31/2010 13:44')
insert into tblTest values ( 29 ,'1/25/2010 9:33','1/26/2010 14:20')
insert into tblTest values ( 30 ,'1/30/2009 11:21','2/2/2009 14:44')
insert into tblTest values ( 31 ,'6/17/2010 9:07','6/18/2010 14:17')
insert into tblTest values ( 32 ,'6/16/2010 10:24','6/17/2010 16:20')
insert into tblTest values ( 33 ,'6/14/2010 9:33','6/15/2010 8:52')
insert into tblTest values ( 34 ,'5/27/2010 9:15','5/28/2010 14:15')
insert into tblTest values ( 35 ,'5/27/2010 10:16','5/28/2010 15:51')
insert into tblTest values ( 36 ,'5/21/2010 9:15','5/23/2010 13:05')
insert into tblTest values ( 37 ,'5/19/2010 10:08','5/20/2010 13:33')
insert into tblTest values ( 38 ,'6/30/2010 11:41','7/1/2010 18:16')
insert into tblTest values ( 39 ,'6/30/2010 11:41','6/30/2010 18:16')
insert into tblTest values ( 40 ,'1/10/2011 9:43','1/11/2011 13:13')

select 
datediff(d, CAST(entered as DATE), CAST(completed as DATE)) AS Sort_Days,
DATEPART(hour, completed) AS Sort_Hours,
CASE datediff(d, CAST(entered as DATE), CAST(completed as DATE))
    WHEN 0 THEN '' WHEN 1 THEN 'NEXT DAY ' WHEN 2 THEN '2ND DAY ' WHEN 3 THEN '3RD DAY ' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10), datediff(d, CAST(entered as DATE), CAST(completed as DATE))) + 'TH DAY ' 
END
+ CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEPART(hour, completed) - CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, completed) > 12 THEN 12 ELSE 0 END )
+ CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, completed) < 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END AS TimeCompleted,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 1 then 1 end as Jan,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 2 then 1 end as Feb,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 3 then 1 end as Mar,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 4 then 1 end as Apr,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 5 then 1 end as May,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 6 then 1 end as Jun,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 7 then 1 end as Jul,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 8 then 1 end as Aug,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 9 then 1 end as Sep,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 10 then 1 end as Oct,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 11 then 1 end as Nov,
case when datepart(month,entered) = 12 then 1 end as Dec
into #tblTest
from tblTest

select TimeCompleted, sum(Jan), sum(Feb), sum(Mar), sum(Apr), sum(May), sum(Jun), sum(Jul), sum(Aug), sum(Sep), sum(Oct), sum(Nov), sum(Dec)
from #tblTest
group by TimeCompleted, Sort_Days, Sort_Hours
order by Sort_Days, Sort_Hours
```

Comment: the ordering isn't great, i fudged it with some spaces. and pm/am ordering won't be correct either.

Comment: sean could you please help me to sort this list? i want to sort it by the first column

Answer (score 2):

You could group on the duration in hours:

```
select  datediff(hour, [DateTime Entered], [DateTime Completed])
,       sum(case when month([DateTime Entered] = 1 then 1 end) as Jan
,       sum(case when month([DateTime Entered] = 2 then 1 end) as Feb
,       sum(case when month([DateTime Entered] = 3 then 1 end) as Mar
,       ...
from    YourTable
group by
        datediff(hour, [DateTime Entered], [DateTime Completed])
```

Re-reading, it seems I can read your question in a second way.  If you'd like to group on the end time (i.e. July 2nd 23:00 to July 3rd 01:00 would count as 25 hours) then you can cast the start time to date:

```
select  datediff(hour, cast([DateTime Entered] as date), [DateTime Completed])
,       sum(case when month([DateTime Entered] = 1 then 1 end) as Jan
,       ...
from    YourTable
group by
        datediff(hour, cast([DateTime Entered] as date), [DateTime Completed])
```

Comment: thank you so much!! does this account for date completed of next day?

Comment: Yeah, if the hour difference is greater than 24, that's certainly the next day.  You could test it with a small dataset.

Comment: thank you again so much for this. this is ALMOST what i need. instead of having the total count of hours can i have the count of IDs completed at 12am, the count of IDs completed at 1am, the count of IDs completed 2am etc........